# How to change the status isActive:false to true

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that method: DELETE, changes the `isActive` from `true` to `false`.

But how can I revert it back from `false` to `true`?

Here's my code to revert it, but I don't know what it lacks:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)

let courseId = params.get('courseId')

let token = localStorage.getItem('token')

fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/courses/${courseId}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers:{
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    if(data === true){
        window.location.replace('./courses.html')
    }else{
        alert("Something went wrong.")
    }
})
```

This is my routes:

```
router.put('/:courseId', auth.verify, (req, res) => { let courseId = req.params.courseId CourseController.unArchive({courseId}).then(resultFromUnArchive => res.send(resultFromUnArchive)) })
```

This is my controller:

```
module.exports.unArchive = (params) => {
    let updateActive2 = {
        isActive: true
    }

    return Course.findOneAndUpdate(params.courseId, updateActive2).then((course, err) => {
        return (err) ? false : true
    })
}
```

I've tried this and it doesn't work

```
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
         isActive:true
        })
```

Comment: Add `body` to fetch.

Comment: @HassanImam it's not working i've added this : 
  `headers: {`
 `'Content-Type':` `'application/json',`
 `'Authorization':` `Bearer ${token}`
 `}`,
 `body: JSON.stringify({`
  `isActive: true`
 `})`

Comment: Does this api exist on the backend?

Comment: yes this is my routes:

`router.put('/:courseId', auth.verify, (req, res) => {`
 `let courseId = req.params.courseId`
 `CourseController.unArchive({courseId}).then(resultFromUnArchive =>` `res.send(resultFromUnArchive))`
`})`


and this is my controllers:


`module.exports.unArchive = (params) => {`
 `let updateActive2 = {`
  `isActive: true`
 `}`

 `return Course.findOneAndUpdate(params.courseId,` `updateActive2).then((course, err) => {`
  `return (err) ? false : true`
 `})`
}

Comment: Are you able to verify if your code is executing controller and route?

Comment: yes it does, I've already checked it

Comment: Can you verify if the value is getting updated in database?

Comment: @HassanImam The value doesn't change, I don't know why.. if there's no error on my code

Comment: Debug inside controller and focus on `findOneAndUpdate`, maybe problem lies there.